# Переформулировать SQl-запрос в LINQ запрос C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Начинаю разбираться с LINQ и пока не могу понять, как переделать SQL-запрос

```
insert into Ck
select p.item1, p.item2, ... , p.itemk-1, q.itemk-1
from Lk-1 p, Lk-1 q
where p.item1 = q.item1, p.item2 = q.item2, ... , p.itemk-2 = q.itemk-2,
p.itemk-1 < q.itemk-1
```

в LINQ.

У меня Ck - это List, а ItemSet - это класс, реализующий словарь типа Dictionary, int). p и q - это List, которые являются ключом в словаре, а p.item и q.item - это элементы типа string.На выходе должен получится объект класса ItemSet.

```
                var nextCadidate = (from pitem in pData 
                                where pitem.Last() < qitem.Last()
                                select pitem)
                                .Concat(from qitem in qData
                                        )
```

Вот пока, что мне удалось придумать, но есть подозрения, что все совсем не так должно быть реализовано.
И можно как-то сразу указать два источника данных, чтобы потом сравнивать их элементы?

Comment: Не очень понял что за странные условия в WHERE через запятую, но похоже что вам нужно использовать ключевое слово join. Пример из офф. документации: `var categoryQuery =
    from cat in categories
    join prod in products on cat equals prod.Category
    select new { Category = cat, Name = prod.Name };`

Comment: @t0lik в условии имеется ввиду, что все itemы у первой и второй коллекци равны, за исключением предпоследнего элемента. А последний элемент у первой коллекции должен быть меньше последнего у второй.

Comment: @t0lik были мысли связать их с помошью join, но не понятно, как именно их связать, т.е. по какому условию? Т. е. первая коллекция представляет собой, допустим, список, а вторая - этот же список, за исключением первого элемента

Comment: `по какому условию` - то что у вас написано в where секции sql это и есть условие соединения.

Comment: Вопрос смотрелся бы лучше, если бы вначале была структура ваших данных, затем желаемое поведение, и  уже потом попытки решения и что именно не получается. Также укажите с каким объемом данных предполагается работать.

Comment: Напишите пример входных данных и выходных, чтобы было очевидно, что надо сделать.